# Stuck with editing image maps in dreamweaver

Tags: html, dictionary, area, dreamweaver

Doing a big part of work around html image maps and suddenly I am not able to edit image maps:
- when clicking on an image with map edit tool, it adds the first point, but then focus is lost and 'multiple CSS p-elements' are selected, so I am not able to create any shapes, but adding single points only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamweaver can only make image maps for images with `position:static`

Answer (score -1):

The image map tools will not be shown if you are in Live-view. Try switching your display to Design-view using the drop list on the toolbar and see if you get them back. This hint is by [MurraySummers](https://community.adobe.com/t5/dreamweaver-discussions/image-map-tool-in-properties-is-gone/m-p/6460044/page/2)  and take a look to the [video-clip from DJO Lessons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eygcyyyVGQI) » Image Maps in Dreamweaver.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35199607)